# Why does the polynomial $x^{n+1}-n!$ have $n+1$ distinct roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Why does the polynomial $x^{n+1}-n!$ have $n+1$ distinct roots in the field of complex numbers?

Comment: Because it has no multiple roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a polynomial of degree $n+1$, $x^{n+1}-n!$ has $n+1$ complex roots.

To show that roots are distinct we check the derivative of    $x^{n+1}-n!$.

Note that if a function f(x) has a root of multiplicity more than $1$ then its derivative will have the same root with multiplicity at least $1$

$$ \frac {d}{dx} ( x^{n+1}-n!)=(n+1)x^n$$ does not have any non zero root and zero is not a root of $x^{n+1}-n!$

Thus $x^{n+1}-n!$ does not have any roots of multiplicity more than $1$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left(\frac{x}{(n!)^{1/(n+1)}}\right)^{n+1}-1=0
$$

the $n+1$ unity roots.

Comment: This answer could be a little bit more detailed...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Do you think it's necessary to explain why there are $k$ distinct $k$-th roots of $1$ in the complex numbers? It's just a simple application of De Moivre’s formula.

Comment: @egreg I think it would be better to explicit the link between the roots of unity and the roots of the polynomial. My problem is not so much about the level of detail as about at least writing a full sentence to answer the question. At first the answer was just the equation, which I personnally think is a bit light for an answer.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I agree

Answer (score 4):

This polynomial has derivative $(n+1)x^n$, the only root of which is $0$. Since $0$ is not a root of $x^{n+1}-n!$, all its complex roots have multiplicity $1$, i.e. are all distinct.

Answer (score 1):

$x^n-a$ has allways $n$ different roots if $a>0$. They are $a^{1/n}e^{2\pi i k/n}$, $k$ from $1$ to $n$.